# Corn stunted in one area of my plot?

Tags: sweetcorn

[image][image]
Can anyone tell me  why this is happening!? When we till after soil, we added composted manure her and 10 1010 fertilizer.  Our seeds are the honey select  variety from a reputable greenhouse in my area. They are treated seeds if that makes a difference. I planted the corn about A month ago and I have seeded the bare spot three times now.  Everything growing in between it is growing wonderfully but why is there a spot, a huge spot come out right in the middle of my corn plot or nothing wants to grow? Things will grow to three or 4 inches tall and then stop and start turning brown or just stop completely without turning brown. I have  added lime because we had a bunch of moss grow because we had a very rainy start to the season so I  raked it off, added lime, until that under. Last week, I side dressed with 10 10 10 fertilizer  and I feed once a week with miracle grow, the water-soluble. I have tried to baby this corn and give it all the nutrients it's been needing so what is going on? Any ideas!? [image]
EDIT:  I am in West Virginia and the un-amended soil  is a very  compacted heavy clay soil. It is a bout a 10 x 12 plot and we used 3 to 4 bags of black kow manure  before planting and we lightly tilled under the manure with a garden claw.

Comment: I want to know about the soil. Where are you? Describe the un-amended soil. What is the clay-sand-organic matter ratio? How deep of a layer of manure did you put in? What kind of manure?

Comment: Look into back to Eden, hill the sides to hold water in, flood it about weekly to tell the corn to grow faster, don't till

Comment: Peter21-  I am in West Virginia and the unamended soil is very dense clay soil and was very compacted. We  put in about three or four bags of black kow manure  and lightly till it in with a garden claw before making the rows.

Comment: You need drainage.Think of the sandy soils of the arid places where corn can grow. Get a shovel and dig deep.You need to turn up all the soil in the garden and loosen it up. If you don't see any little gravely rocks, you'll have to add some of your own drainage material. The soil should gritty and scratchy when you run it through your hands. It won't happen this year, that's for sure.

Comment: Peter21- thank you! I'll  make sure we do that next year! This is my first year growing corn and it's already almost 3 foot tall except in that one bare spot where it will stunt around 6 inches tall. I will definitely be taking your advice next year and adding soil amendments and probably some organic soil on top of what's already there as well.  When that area didn't start growing when the rest of it dead, I don't know some of the seeds in that circle  and they were extremely soggy and mushy and didn't even germinate. But when I reseeded after it had dried out, they start germinating...

Comment: ...but then they started getting stunted . I thought since they started germinating after the second seeding  it was OK but I guess it's still pretty soggy right there

Answer (score 1):

I am posting here simply to provide an option that removes the question from of the ‘unanswered’ list.

I believe the multiple commenters have nailed this by fingering drainage.  Corn’s pretty finicky, especially about that.  As you drive, I mean, bicycle, around and see cornfields, notice how much the plant sizes vary in small parts of fields.  It can be easy to find examples of corn stagnating in low spots where drainage is poor.